# Does Magento newsletter system process bounces?

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, newsletter

Does Magento newsletter system process mail bounces?

Or do I need a plugin for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It **does not** process mail bounces natively. Hard/soft bounces (connections receiving an error status) are a function of your [Mail Transport agent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_transfer_agent#List_of_MTA_software_for_Unix-like_operating_systems). Other "bounces" such as vacation replies or unsubscribe replies would have to be analyzed by intercepting mail in an actual inbox.

I would recommend you to look at hosted SMTP services or an ESP such as Mailchimp which have tight integration with Magento's email services to handle this type of requirement.

Comment: Magento's newsletter management is anemic at best. It's lead to several promotional email service providers (ESPs) writing their own extensions that will even do abandoned cart remails. dotMailer, MailChimp, BubbleBox, etc. will integrate, pull the info from Magento and then handle the dirty work on the other side such as bounce, unsubscribe, etc. and also more importantly, protect your website and domain from being blacklisted so all your transactional emails don't get bitbucketed.